How to format units inside math environment?
I want to answer the following question:
Which of these options would be an acceptable way of writing A = 12 cm^2 in LaTeX? Select all that apply.

$A = 12\text{ cm}^2$
\(A = 12 cm^2\)
\(A = \mathrm{12\, cm^2}\)
\(A = 12\text{ cm}^2\)
\(A = 12\mathrm{ cm^2}\)
\(A = 12\text{ cm^2}\)

I think number 1, 3, 4, 6 are correct. What do you think?

1,2,4,6 definitely wrong, but look at the siunitx package

#6 doesn't compile, so it cannot ever be an acceptable solution...

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727853

Let's make a test:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
1. \verb+$12\text{ cm}^2$+               & $12\text{ cm}^2$ \\
2. \verb+\(12 cm^2\)+                    & \(12 cm^2\) \\
3. \verb+\(\mathrm{12\, cm^2}\)+         & \(\mathrm{12\, cm^2}\) \\
4. \verb+\(12\text{ cm}^2\)+             & \(12\text{ cm}^2\) \\
5. \verb+\(12\mathrm{ cm^2}\)+           & \(12\mathrm{ cm^2}\) \\
6. \verb+\(12\text{ cm^2}\)+             & WRONG! \\ %\(12\text{ cm^2}\) \\
7. \verb+\qty{12}{\centi\meter\squared}+ & \qty{12}{\centi\meter\squared} \\
8. \verb+\qty{12}{cm^2}+                 & \qty{12}{cm^2} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Note that 6 is syntactically wrong. And \text is conceptually wrong in any case, because it would pick up the font current outside the formula, which could well be italic.
The only reasonable alternative to siunitx and \qty is 3. But it's cumbersome.
Possibly 12\,\mathrm{cm}^2 would be less cumbersome, but there's no reason to avoid siunitx, which you should consult the documentation of.
More details:

The space is too wide; the BIPM recommends a thin space.
The unit symbol should be in upright type (and there's no space).
Cumbersome, better 12\,\mathrm{cm}^2
This is exactly the same as 1.
Missing space.
^2 is illegal inside \text.


Thanks for your detailed answer. You know I am doing it in multiple-choice questions test when I answer it says it is wrong and the instruction is Not quite! Remember to examine the delimiters and the use of \mathrm{ } and \text{ }.

@SarzamineDanesh it must be one of those tests where the real point is to test your insight into the setter's mind. so you probably have to figure out which answer the setter wants rather than which one is actually correct. I've had professional development modules like this, where to pass the human resources test I had to guess how hr wanted me to answer rather than which answer was correct. it's just not testing the skill you expected ;).

I can't see the reason you've given for (4) applies there. the ^2 isn't inside the \text{} as it is in (6), is it?

@Mico but that's not a syntax error like (6). the answer says both 4 and 6 are syntactically wrong (and that \text is also conceptually wrong). but (4) seems unlike (6) in the first respect.

@cfr I’ll fix it

@egreg thanks ... (I have no idea whether to delete my comments.)

Rather than reinvent the (typographic) wheel, I'd always rely on the siunitx package and its very handy \qty macro, which takes two arguments: (a) a numerical quantity and (b) an associated (scientific) unit.
I can think of three possible solution methods, which all produce the same output:

If used correctly, the output of \qty is pretty much guaranteed to be typographically correct. Armed with this finding, I'd say that of the 6 variants the OP considered, only #3 attains the optimum. (#6 doesn't even compile, and #4 fails if it is not used while in upright-text mode.) That said, I'd argue that \qty{12}{\centi\meter\squared} is a lot more "LaTeX-y" than \mathrm{12\,cm^2} is. Moreover, \qty can be used in both text and math modes, whereas \mathrm is obviously restricted to math mode only.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \qty macro

\begin{document}
7. $A = \qty{12}{cm^2}$  % "literal mode" -- thanks, Joseph Wright

8. $A = \qty{12}{\centi\meter\squared}$

9. $A = \qty{12}{\centi\meter\tothe2}$
\end{document}


You've missed \qty{12}{cm^2} - 'literal mode' clealy. although your #8 is also using that

@JosephWright - Thanks for this. I've updated my answer. :-)

Outside the LaTeX and without siunitx package we can write
$A = 12\,{\rm cm}^2$.

\bye


Well 'perhaps' - there is the long-standing question of whether one should set units as mathematical or non-mathematical material, and this depends on ones view on the nature of units; either way, I'd encourage some semantic mark-up - plain users hopefully need no guidance in creating their own macros :)

As an alternative, if you wish to express quantities solely in SI units without prefixes, you can use mandi (requires LuaLaTeX). The innovation is to simply name the quantity and the correct SI unit will appear. You must do any scaling manually or numerically in place using LaTeX's floating point math. (Disclaimer: I am the author of mandi.)
MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mandi}

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph \( \area{1.2\timestento{-3}} \) with an area.

\itshape This is a paragraph \( \area{1.2\timestento{-3}} \) with an area.

\bfseries This is a paragraph \( \area{1.2\timestento{-3}} \) with an area.

\normalfont This is a paragraph \( \area{1.2\timestento{-3}} \) with an area.

This is a paragraph \( \area{\fpeval{round(12/100^2,4)}} \) with an area.
\end{document}



It doesn't seem to produce “centimeters” or “picofarad” or…

If you don’t use siunitx, I recommend \textup{\,cm}^2. This appears upright if used within italic text such as a theorem statement, but retains the weight if used in a bold header.
It also keeps the current font family if used in a sans-serif section. You can add \rmfamily or \sffamily inside the braces to override the font family. Although at that point, you’d want to define your own command. which would be no simpler than siunitx.

The answer is the 3rd and 5th ones. Here is the reasoning:

you want to write this inline using )...)
there is no space between 12 and cm
correct
correct
there is no space between 12 and cm
you cannot put ^2 in the {}


Welcome to TeX.SE.  You say "the 3rd and 5th", but then you list 3 and 4 as correct and 5 as incorrect.  Other answers are somewhat similar to yours, although they point out that if you're in an italic paragraph (for example, a theorem), then 4 will become italic.  Also, 3 and 4 have different spacing, so I don't know that they can both be correct.  Also also, using $ for inline math is ok.
